# Formato de campo para guardar tempo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Qual campo devo utilizar no SQL Server para guardar um tempo de duração? Ex.: 2Dias 23H 47Min 00Sec.

Se tiver um exemplo com Fluente API vai ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O tipo correto do .NET para representar durações de tempo é o [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

É possível usar o tipo [`Time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) para guardar esse dado, de acordo com essa [tabela de compatibilidade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Usando .NET 6 para frente é possível adotar o [`TimeOnly`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/49036).

Algo que o pessoal costuma fazer também é usar um `INT` ou `BIGINT` para guardar os [*ticks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_TimeSpan_Ticks) ou [milissegundos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.milliseconds?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_TimeSpan_Milliseconds) ou mesmo [segundos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.seconds?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_TimeSpan_Seconds), de acordo com a precisão que necessita.

Como a pergunta não dá detalhes, não posso ir além disto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando eu uso Timespan o EF está mapeando para Time(7). Ao tentar inserir recebo este erro "Estouro SqlDbType.Time. O valor '3.03:03:00' está fora do intervalo. Ele deve estar entre 00:00:00.0000000 e 23:59:59.9999999."

Comment: Isto já é outro problema, coloque em detalhes em uma nova pergunta. Sem detalhes do que está fazendo não temos como ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para armazenar contagem de tempo que seja inferior a 24 horas, pode utilizar TIME. Mas se o acumulado ultrapassa 24 horas, como você cita, então pode utilizar ou datetime ou int.

Ao utilizar o tipo datetime, deve-se iniciar com 0. Após, vá somando/subtraindo as horas, minutos e segundos. A qualquer momento, para exibir o valor no formato hhh:mm, pode utilizar a fórmula

```
   (valor / 60) + ':' + (valor % 60)
```

Para avaliar o que ocorre quando se usa datetime:

```
-- código #1
declare @Horas datetime;

-- zera a variável
set @Horas= 0;
PRINT @Horas

-- soma 40 horas
set @Horas= DateAdd(hour, +40, @Horas);
PRINT @Horas

-- soma 38 minutos
set @Horas= DateAdd(minute, +38, @Horas);
PRINT @Horas

-- subtrai 128 minutos
set @Horas= DateAdd(minute, -128, @Horas);
PRINT @Horas

-- exibe no formato hhh:mm
PRINT Cast(DateDiff(minute, 0, @Horas) / 60 as varchar(10)) + 'h' + Right('00' + Cast(DateDiff(minute, 0, @Horas) % 60 as varchar(2)), 2) + 'min'
```

Mas uma coluna do tipo int ocupa menos espaço do que uma do tipo datetime. Por isso, me parece que a melhor implementação continua sendo com uma coluna do tipo INT.